# PromQL - Prometheus - query value as label

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql

Some query returns:

```
{id="cart"}     0.014961101137043577
{id="payment"}  0.014961101137043577
{id="products"} 0.013670539986329524
```

But I would like to have:

```
{id="cart", a="0.014961101137043577"}     1
{id="payment", a="0.014961101137043577"}  1
{id="products", a="0.013670539986329524"} 1
```

I've looked everywhere, but I am worried that this is not possible ;/

Answer (score 1):

I found something interesting, it is kind of hack:

```
count_values without() ("my_new_label", start_metric)
```